# How to convert Cordova application to Phonegap

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, phonegap

I am developing a plugin in Cordova for iOS users, which can be used by clients inside there applications. Now, can I use/provide the same plugin to PhoneGap users? Is it possible or do I need to make changes to support PhoneGap?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Phonegap](https://phonegap.com/) is a distribution of Cordova (similar to Chrome vs Chromium).

> From the team behind Apache Cordova, the Adobe PhoneGap framework is an open source distribution of Cordova

Hence they use the same plugins so no changes are necessary.

Note that [Phonegap Build](https://build.phonegap.com/) is not the same as Phonegap - it's a cloud-build service offered by Adobe and there are some differences when it comes to using plugins vs building locally with the Cordova/Phonegap CLI (e.g. Phonegap Build doesn't support plugins that use [hook scripts](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/appdev/hooks/)).

Comment: Thank you DaveAlden. Your answer helps.